# Error is occurring InvalidPipeArgument Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, date, firebase, timestamp

### Below is a brief explanation of what is happening:

1. I updated my application for the new version of Angular, updated from 5 to 6.
2. I updated all `packages.json` deployments using `ng update` command.

I'm saving a `Date()` value in the **Cloud Firestore** database, field **birthday_date (timestamp)** using an input on my page with the [DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) component of the [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/).

1. Before doing the dependency updates, a value of type `Date ()` was
   returned from the database in the **birthday_date (timestamp)**
   field, so I could use `{{ data.birthday_date | date }}`.
2. After updates to the dependencies in `package.json` you are
   returning a value of type `Timestamp` in the **birthday_date
   (timestamp)** field.
3. Now I need to call the `toDate ()` method to get the `Date ()` object.

   `{{ data.birthday_date.toDate() | date }}`

> The return before was a `Date ()` object:
>
> `Sat May 19 2018 20:35:12 GMT-0300`
>
> After updating the return is a `Timestamp` object:
>
> `Timestamp {seconds: 1527476400, nanoseconds: 0}`

Updated in `package.json` the dependencies:

```
"firebase": "4.11.0", ->
"firebase": "5.0.3"


"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6", ->
"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.9",
```

### Below is part of my application code:

**mycomponent.component.html:**

```
<form name="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" class="w-100-p">
<mat-form-field fxFlex="30">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="birthday_date " placeholder="Date of birth">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker startView="multi-year" disabled="false" touchUi="true"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Not displaying the date in the input because you are returning a `Timestamp`, and the [DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) component needs a `Date ()` value.

**list.component.ts:**

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="birthday_date">
        <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header fxHide fxShow.gt-xs>Date of birth</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let data" fxHide fxShow.gt-xs>
           <p class="text-truncate">{{ data.birthday_date | date }}</p>
        </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

If I do not call the `toDate ()` method `{{ data.birthday_date.toDate() | date }}` the following error is occurring:

```
ListComponent.html:81 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Timestamp(seconds=1526698800, nanoseconds=0)" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4238)
    at DatePipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.DatePipe.transform (common.js:5151)
    at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (core.js:10801)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:11375)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:11333)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11970)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:11956)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ListComponent.html:81)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11948)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11320)
```

### Solution I am looking for:

I need to change somehow to return an object of type `Date()` instead of a `Timestamp`, as this has impacted many places in my application and is delaying my entire project.

Comment: could you find a solution? I have the same problem. when I use for example: `{{dateCreation.toDate () | date: 'medium' }}` If it returns a date () value and appears correctly but it generates the following error: `TypeError: Can not read property 'toDate' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it like this:

> data.birthday_date.seconds * 1000 | date